# cp: target '/root/var/www/html/' is not a directory

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, operating-system, sh

I am using Ubuntu windows 10 bash and I'd like to move a project from /mnt/i/Projects/Template to run it on Apache server which located in /var/www/html.

I tried to copy a folder from a direct to new directly but unfortunately I got an error which is:

> cp -r /mnt/i/Projects/Template ~/var/www/html/
>   cp: target '/root/var/www/html/' is not a directory

I would like to test those templates with Apache and I tried to change Apache directly.

Another test I did:

> root@DESKTOP-4PBGG1N:/var/www# ls -ld ~/var ~/var/www ~/var/www/html
>   ls: cannot access '/root/var': No such file or directory
>   ls: cannot access '/root/var/www': No such file or directory
>   ls: cannot access '/root/var/www/html': No such file or directory

Comment: You could add the output of an `ls -ld ~/var ~/var/www ~/var/www/html/` to your question.

Comment: root@DESKTOP-4PBGG1N:/var/www# ls -ld ~/var ~/var/www ~/var/www/html
ls: cannot access '/root/var': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/root/var/www': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/root/var/www/html': No such file or directory

Comment: @ImadOLHO : You say that the server is below `/var/...` but you copy to `~/var/...` instead.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the directory for the apache server is not in root it's just "/var/www/html". If it still doesn't work you probably doesn't have apache installed, you can do that by running these two lines "lsb_release -a" and "sudo apt-get install apache2". There will come an error when trying to launch the apache server (with "sudo service apache2 start"), but just ignore it you can still use it without any problems. Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

try creating directory if the only problem is `'/root/var/www/html/'` not being a directory

```
# mkdir -pv ~/var/www/html/ 
# cp -r /mnt/i/Projects/Template ~/var/www/html/
```

before that just make sure that apache is installed and configured

have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

For instance you have a file in Documents called index.php and to be copied in the /root/var/www/html/ directory you have to do it this way:
First don't forget to use sudo to be super user and then

```
- sudo cp -Rv index.php /var/www/html or
- sudo cp -Rv index.php /root/var/www/html
```

And you will get this output: 'index.php' -> '/var/www/html/index.php'

-R for copy folders &
-v for see what folders and files are copied